# How to store data in a class with multiple variations

Tags: java

So I'm kinda curious how can I store for example a list of items in my class with prices, code, quantity and so on.

Is there an easy way to have it all related and not creating a function for each variable?

Comment: You mean like a variable?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Please show some code or pseudocode, if you dont have an idea, how to implement it in java

Comment: 'how can I store for example a list of items in my class with prices, code, quantity and so on' ...by just doing exactly that; create an Item class with price, code, & quantity members and make a `List<>` of them.

Comment: ... create a class for your items (`public class Product`) and define the consturctor and the variables (price, code, quantity, ...) in this class. In your other class you can then make a list (for example ArrayList<Produkt>) and store all the items in this list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a List object in your class.

For example a person that has credit cards:

```
public Class Person {

   private String name;
   private List<CreditCard> creditCards;

   // toString, equals, constructor, etc.

   public void setCreditCards(List<CreditCard> creditCards) {
      this.creditCards = creditCards;
   }

   public List<Creditcard> getCreditCards() {
      return this.creditCards;
   }

   // more getters and setters
```

And the Credit Card:

```
public Class CreditCard {

    private String number;
    private Date expiryDate;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And then you can make calls like this:

```
Person person = new Person();
List<CreditCard> cards = person.getCreditCards();
for(CreditCard card: cards) {
    String number = card.getNumber();
}
```

Comment: (your class is called User, but later you call i t Person^^)

Comment: Yeah I just saw that haha, fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

A Java class can be thought of as a collection of fields (variables), and methods (functions).

The way you make a class hold more than one piece of data is to add more fields, and more methods to access those fields.

For example:

```
public class Cat {
    int id;

    String name;

    double price;

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    //........etc
}
```

You can then store that in your list and access different bits of data.